# Calculating mobile displacement based on acceleration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, displacement, data

I have written a mobile app that measures x y z accelerations. I am trying to convert the acceleration results into displacement but dont think a simple $d=\frac 1 2 {a {t^2}}$ will do the job. We have friction forces etc which will possibly effect the calculations. I have included a sample result where I simply push my mobile 5cm on one direction. Even though I push the mobile in 1 direction you can see that the acceleration oscillates around 0 line. You can use this if you think you got the right formulas.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the raw data if you need.

```
-0.002 -0.002 -0.253 13076.385
-0.002 -0.002 -0.228 13108.276
-0.008 0.002 -0.198 13126.648
-0.008 0.002 -0.178 13144.867
-0.007 0.002 -0.160 13161.835
-0.003 0.005 -0.144 13176.514
-0.002 0.001 -0.133 13209.686
0.001 0.001 -0.120 13226.684
0.001 0.004 -0.105 13243.408
0.001 0.004 -0.094 13261.383
-0.003 0.003 -0.085 13278.442
0.005 -0.000 -0.076 13298.523
0.004 -0.000 -0.069 13328.522
0.000 -0.000 -0.065 13344.848
0.000 -0.000 -0.059 13360.870
0.000 -0.000 -0.053 13378.021
0.000 0.003 -0.048 13410.065
0.000 0.003 -0.043 13427.124
-0.003 -0.004 -0.038 13443.146
-0.003 -0.004 -0.035 13460.388
-0.003 -0.000 -0.028 13477.814
-0.002 -0.000 -0.025 13511.169
0.001 -0.000 -0.026 13527.679
-0.002 0.003 -0.016 13543.945
-0.002 0.003 -0.015 13561.249
-0.002 0.003 -0.013 13578.003
-0.005 0.002 -0.015 13610.168
-0.005 -0.001 -0.014 13627.136
-0.001 -0.008 -0.012 13643.951
-0.001 -0.007 -0.011 13660.187
0.006 0.000 -0.010 13676.758
0.006 0.000 -0.009 13708.435
-0.005 0.000 -0.008 13725.311
0.002 -0.003 -0.007 13741.699
0.005 0.004 -0.014 13758.545
0.005 0.004 -0.012 13792.145
0.001 -0.000 -0.011 13809.906
0.001 -0.000 -0.010 13826.629
0.001 -0.000 -0.002 13846.466
-0.003 0.003 -0.002 13861.084
-0.003 0.003 -0.002 13879.639
-0.002 0.003 -0.001 13895.111
0.001 -0.001 -0.001 13927.337
-0.002 -0.001 -0.001 13946.533
-0.002 -0.001 0.002 13963.531
-0.002 -0.001 0.002 13978.943
-0.002 -0.001 -0.008 14011.047
0.006 -0.004 -0.008 14026.855
0.005 -0.004 -0.007 14043.487
-0.006 -0.003 0.004 14062.256
-0.005 -0.003 0.004 14079.651
0.002 -0.003 -0.003 14113.739
-0.002 0.004 -0.007 14131.470
-0.001 0.004 -0.006 14147.766
-0.001 0.004 0.008 14164.734
-0.001 -0.000 0.004 14180.420
-0.001 -0.000 0.004 14196.472
-0.001 -0.000 -0.007 14228.973
-0.001 -0.000 -0.006 14244.812
0.003 0.003 -0.006 14261.444
-0.001 -0.000 0.002 14278.473
-0.001 -0.000 0.002 14311.706
-0.004 -0.000 0.001 14328.094
-0.004 -0.000 0.001 14344.787
0.003 -0.007 0.001 14360.870
0.003 -0.003 -0.002 14376.434
0.003 -0.003 -0.002 14408.722
-0.001 0.004 0.002 14425.567
-0.001 0.004 0.001 14452.057
-0.001 0.004 0.001 14468.384
-0.004 -0.000 0.001 14487.671
-0.004 -0.000 0.001 14502.228
0.004 0.003 0.001 14531.799
-0.000 -0.004 -0.003 14553.741
-0.000 -0.004 -0.002 14580.047
0.007 0.000 -0.006 14600.525
0.006 0.000 -0.005 14600.860
-0.001 0.004 0.002 14617.401
-0.001 -0.004 0.002 14648.224
-0.001 -0.003 0.002 14664.337
-0.005 0.004 -0.002 14683.288
-0.004 -0.003 0.002 14711.212
-0.004 -0.003 0.002 14729.339
0.000 -0.003 -0.002 14748.840
0.000 -0.002 -0.002 14765.533
0.000 0.001 -0.002 14781.921
0.000 0.005 0.002 14798.248
0.000 0.004 0.002 14831.726
0.000 0.000 0.002 14848.175
0.000 0.000 0.001 14863.769
0.000 0.000 0.001 14879.577
0.000 0.000 -0.009 14899.658
0.000 0.000 -0.008 14932.190
-0.110 0.014 0.003 14949.921
-0.058 -0.015 0.003 14966.217
-0.052 -0.013 0.002 14982.849
-0.095 -0.009 0.002 15015.686
-0.086 -0.008 0.002 15016.174
-0.070 -0.004 -0.002 15047.607
-0.001 0.014 0.002 15063.110
-0.001 0.013 0.002 15079.681
-0.001 -0.013 0.002 15095.489
0.030 0.009 -0.002 15128.509
0.027 0.008 -0.002 15144.501
0.069 0.014 0.002 15160.187
0.062 0.013 0.002 15176.910
0.104 0.005 -0.002 15209.717
0.091 0.004 -0.002 15227.020
0.081 0.004 -0.002 15243.652
0.125 0.007 -0.001 15260.254
0.112 0.006 -0.001 15276.794
0.050 0.009 -0.001 15310.028
0.055 -0.023 -0.001 15327.179
0.049 -0.021 -0.001 15342.956
0.024 -0.001 0.003 15360.626
-0.037 -0.001 -0.001 15377.350
-0.033 -0.001 -0.001 15409.363
-0.030 0.003 0.006 15427.917
-0.027 0.002 0.005 15444.519
-0.024 -0.001 0.001 15461.426
-0.022 0.002 0.001 15477.447
-0.020 0.002 0.001 15509.918
-0.021 -0.005 -0.002 15527.801
-0.019 -0.005 -0.002 15544.739
-0.024 -0.008 -0.005 15561.828
-0.018 0.000 -0.001 15578.247
-0.016 0.000 -0.001 15611.084
-0.008 0.003 -0.001 15627.197
-0.011 0.007 0.002 15644.073
-0.010 0.006 0.002 15660.614
-0.012 -0.002 -0.005 15677.246
-0.011 -0.001 -0.004 15709.473
-0.006 0.002 -0.001 15727.173
-0.006 0.002 -0.001 15744.110
-0.005 0.002 -0.000 15761.688
-0.001 -0.002 -0.004 15777.893
-0.004 0.002 0.003 15811.432
-0.004 0.002 0.003 15829.712
-0.004 -0.002 0.003 15845.581
-0.003 -0.002 0.002 15862.915
0.001 -0.002 0.002 15882.110
-0.003 -0.005 -0.001 15896.820
-0.003 -0.004 -0.001 15928.924
0.001 0.003 -0.001 15944.977
0.001 0.003 -0.001 15961.456
0.004 -0.001 -0.004 15978.180
0.004 -0.004 0.006 16010.284
0.003 -0.004 0.006 16029.571
-0.000 -0.000 -0.002 16046.722
-0.000 -0.000 -0.002 16065.216
-0.000 -0.000 -0.001 16081.817
-0.007 -0.000 -0.001 16098.053
-0.006 -0.000 -0.001 16129.150
-0.002 -0.000 0.006 16145.843
-0.002 -0.000 0.005 16163.055
-0.002 -0.000 0.005 16179.565
-0.002 0.003 -0.003 16213.592
-0.002 0.003 -0.002 16230.499
0.006 -0.001 0.005 16247.162
```

Comment: Area under the acceleration-time plot gives the velocity. The area under the velocity -time plot gives the displacement. Just numerically integrate the values you have using something like Simpsons rule. Remember to use the right units.

Comment: That doesn't quite work. S you can see accelerations are both negative and positive almost same value while I am pushing the mobile only to 1 direction.

Comment: Did you move your phone in the x direction? At what time did you start moving it?. Seems like you turned your sensors on and moved the phone vertically before moving it.

Comment: Where the acceleration is increasing rapidly is when it is moving. Ignore the z one as it is not really much of issue. x and y can be difficult to work out as each android phone may have different way showing it but in this picture X should be the movement direction.

Comment: When I start to push the phone, most likely the sensor is left behind and shows a negative acceleration, when I stop the phone the sensor is accelerating and possibly thats why it shows first negative and then positive even though it is in the same direction. When I use the absolute of the results it seems to be working fairly good.

Comment: I don't know if using the absolute value of the acceleration is a physically sound way to do it.  But integrating your data doesn't give 5cm.

Comment: You need to perform _numerical integration_. Like Euler's method https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/eulers-method-explained-with-examples/. Also I think it's weird that the z-acceleration changes. Is your data raw acceleration or is gravity automatically excluded? (Android for example gives you both raw and without gravity).

Comment: Also note that getting position from acceleration data might be tricky using just your phone sensors http://www.chrobotics.com/library/accel-position-velocity. You need high accuracy accelerometers as well as high accuracy orientation measurements.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is Dead Reckoning with [Inertial Navigation Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system). Like others have suggested, you essentially want to do calculus on the data provided. Keep in mind that you need to do the calculus on the x y and z coordinates individually.

In performing the integration, there might be better techniques than a repeated Simpson's rule. A [leap frogging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration)  or  [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) might give a smaller cumulative error. You'd need to adjust the standard form for second order differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

Now is the perfect moment to get introduced to the world of calculus. Go learn it, specifically, Integration.

The problem with $d=0.5at^2$ is that it is based on the assumption that acceleration $a$ is constant. Look at your graphs... Is any acceleration constant ? No.
So, this equation is useless.

However, you can still approximate the displacement from this jaggy zig-zag accelerations. Calculus+Mechanics will help.

Comment: I was looking for an answer not a lecture. I can do calculus bit in excel and it is not an issue.

Comment: hehehe, sorry I didn't realise. But if you can do all this, then what is your problem, specifically? biryani already suggested Simpson's rule.